# java download file does not work in file size is more than 8K?

Tags: java

i try to download a pdf file from url using the code below. It works fine when the file size is under 8k and if the file is up to 8k, it downloads the pdf file but the file is not readable.

Code

```
 InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                 ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                 byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                 int n = 0;
                 while (-1!=(n=in.read(buf)))
                 {
                    out.write(buf, 0, n);
                 }
                 out.close();
                 in.close();
                 byte[] response = out.toByteArray();

                 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\temp\\TEST.pdf"));
                 fos.write(response);
                 fos.close();
                 System.out.println("Download Finished");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to download large files without memory issues in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106775/how-to-download-large-files-without-memory-issues-in-java)

Comment: -1!=(n=in.read(buf) looks odd to me cuz it is c style I guess?. why not (n=in.read(buf)!= -1

Comment: I've used your code to download http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf (424 K) and it worked well. If your URL requires some sort of redirection, you'll end up downloading an html page instead of your pdf. So inspect your saved file and check if it's not an HTML file instead.

Comment: You were right Leo, i tried the same code from home last night when  all activities were low at my company and my code downloaded the pdf file in the right format. And when i tried with one of the previous url it was an html file. So the explaination could be the network activities? or what?  How could it be redirected? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the **IOUtils.copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output)**
You can minimize the lines of code.
[Apache IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29)

Comment: it's easier this way, but why it will fix his/her problem?

Comment: Or, use [Files.copy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) and avoid the dependency on a third-party library.

Comment: i forgot to explain how i get the url, it s during a selenium test where i click on a link to download the file. So here the missing code:  driver.findElement(By.linkText(DownloadPDFlink)).click(); then i try to get the url with System.out.println("HREF ="+driver.findElement(By.linkText(DownloadPDF)).getAttribute("href")); and after i use thr url object to download the file.